# How to change the source of js/css/img to another subdomain?

Tags: vue.js, subdomain, vue-cli

How to change the source of script/style/image to another domain say `cdn.example.com` with vue cli build?

For example after the build I get in index.html the following content:

```
...
<script src=/js/runtime~app.6804cb6b.js></script>
<script src=/js/chunk-vendors.8aaf819c.js></script>
<script src=/js/app.018b8fef.js></script>
</body></html>
```

The expected output need to be:

```
  ...
    <script src=https://cdn.example.com/myapp/js/runtime~app.6804cb6b.js></script>
    <script src=https://cdn.example.com/myapp/js/chunk-vendors.8aaf819c.js></script>
    <script src=https://cdn.example.com/myapp/js/app.018b8fef.js></script>
    </body></html>
```

Is it possible with vue cli build?

Comment: Are you using vue with webpack? This is a bundler question unrelated to vue

Comment: vue/cli used webpack under the hood

Comment: Ah, in that case you may need to eject in order to change the appropriate webpack settings

Comment: I prefer vue/cli solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `publicPath` in your vue cli config:

> `publicPath`: The base URL your application bundle will be deployed at (known as `baseUrl` before Vue CLI 3.3). This is the equivalent of webpack's `output.publicPath`, but Vue CLI also needs this value for other purposes, so you should always use `publicPath` instead of modifying webpack `output.publicPath`.

See [the vue CLI documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

Comment: Yes, the mechanism is the same